# Construct a measurable subset E such that $\lim_{\delta \to 0}\frac{1}{2\delta}\int_{p+\delta}^{p-\delta}\chi_E(x)dx=a$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $0<a<1$ be a fixed constant . 
Construct a measurable subset E of $\mathbb{R}$ such that , for some $p\in E$  , we have $$\lim_{\delta \to 0}\frac{1}{2\delta}\int_{p+\delta}^{p-\delta}\chi_E(x)dx=a$$

Comment: what did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can build it by parts, Just make sure that the measure of the set in the intervals $(p+\frac{1}{n+1},p+\frac{1}{n})$ and $(p-\frac{1}{n+1},p-\frac{1}{n})$ is equal to $a(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1})=\frac{a}{n(n+1})$.

Since $\lim\frac{1}{n(n+1)}/{\frac{1}{n+1}}=0$ this set will satisfy $\lim_{\delta \to 0}\frac{1}{2\delta}\int_{p+\delta}^{p-\delta}\chi_E(x)dx=a$

Comment: Thank for your answer.
But I dont know why we should chose two intervals $(p+\frac{1}{n+1},p+\frac{1}{n})$ and $(p-\frac{1}{n+1},p-\frac{1}{n})$ is equal to $a(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1})=\frac{a}{n(n+1})$.
If I let the measure of the set  $(p-\frac{1}{n},p+\frac{1}{n})$ is equal to a(\frac{2}{n}) , it will also right ?

Comment: No, because in this construction the measure of the part of the set inside the  interval is $a$ multiplied by the length of the interval, which is what yo want.

Comment: But if I choose the interval $(p-\frac{1}{n},p+\frac{1}{n})$ and it measure is $a(\frac{2}{n})$ . I think it also satisfy $\lim_{\delta \to 0}\frac{1}{2\delta}\int_{p+\delta}^{p-\delta}\chi_E(x)dx=a$. Is there have anything wrong but I dont find ?